# How to get LibreOffice's document binary?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-basic

I'm just starting to develop extensions to LibreOffice suite and I'd like to get the binary of the current active document. In fact I'd like to do something similar to an ajax request where I'd sent this document. Any ideia?

Comment: "The current active document" is XML, not binary.

Answer (score 0):

As ngulam stated, the document proper is XML.

The raw file on disk is stored in a ZIP container. You can find the URL to this disk from the document and then access this ZIP container directly. I do not believe that it is possible, however, to see the document as a binary blob (or even the XML as stored in the ZIP container) using the API and accessing what has been loaded into memory.

Can you clarify your question. For example, are you attempting to access binary portions such as an inserted graphic into a document?

Comment: I had plans to encode my document in 64enconding string so that I could send it through ajax...